# Where can I find social/population Information on dinosaurs before the hatch?

Tags: jurassic-world-evolution

After they are hatched/released you can see that in their information window. But where can I find them before if I want to plan which dinosaurs to put together?

The 2nd tab would have the actual numbers, but I don't have a screenshot of that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Afair there isn't an option in the current version of the game.

What you can do (and what i will do in the future) is to hatch each dinosaur on the sandbox island and note the information somewhere else for later use

Edit:
Now after the 1.4 Update you can see these information in the second tab in the breeding station after selecting a dinosaur